# How to get rid of ubuntu Desktop window in i3 wm?

Tags: window, i3-wm

I am using `i3` window manager. And have a problem with appearing of `Ubuntu` Desktop window when I open, for example, downloaded files in `Firefox` (Annoying window is on the right). Actually, the problem is not with appearing of that window but with closing it. I am simply not able to do it. I tried `Ctrl+Alt+Q` but nothing happens. What Should I do?[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That annoying window on the side is usually due to the starting of `nautilus`. If you use `nautilus --no-desktop` to open it then there will be no such `destop` window.

In case that window opens up then use `pkill nautilus`.

Comment: You can also use <code>xkill</code> to directly remove the window by clicking it on it

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is that the following will substitute/alias `nautilus --no-desktop` for `nautilus`.  This is highly desirable as many mouse-driven applications like zotero will launch the default file manager (nautilus), leaving no opportunity for you to type `nautilus --no-desktop` at a terminal prompt.

Create an alias in your `.bashrc` file.  In my Ubuntu 16.04 installation, that file is `/home/myUsername/.bashrc`.  The alias is created by adding the following line to the end of that file:

`alias nautilus='nautilus --no-desktop'`

I just got this to work and have only tested it once.

Answer (score 1):

If you use another file manager such as thunar already, you can uninstall nautilus so that Firefox is forced to use the next sensible default instead:

`sudo apt remove nautilus`